# How do we prove that parallel light rays (which are not parallel of principal axis) meet at focal plane?

Tags: optics, lenses

Parallel rays coming from infinity are said to meet at focal plane.I was looking for the proof of that phenomena

Comment: Do you mean after they pass through a converging lens?

Comment: After they pass through a converging  lens or get reflected by a concave mirror

Comment: Use the ABCD matrix formalism.

Comment: I think the search term you want is "non-axial ray". And I've seen a interesting paper on the pedogogy of the subject recently (perhaps in *The Physics Teacher*).

Comment: You can prove it for a spherical glass or mirror of a small curvature. You can also prove it for a parabolic mirror with a non-small curvature. A glass of a non-small curvature should be aspheric, but I am not sure of its exact shape.

Comment: What kind of proof are you looking for?  Mathematical?  Graphical?

Answer (score 1):

The proof is “by construction”:  the lens, mirror or more complicated optics system was constructed to do exactly that.

Why is that useful?  It maps light arriving at each particular *angle* to a specific *point* on the focal plane. Since light from different points on a distant object arrive at different angles, this lets the optical system form an image of the distant object.

Comment: But how they know how to construct it? It is impossible that apply Snell's law in every point of the lens.

Comment: @AntoniosSarikas Why?

Answer (score 0):

you put a screen behind the lens, and you will see the light make a small spot as you move the screen. There lies your focal point.